# KMggplot2 plugin only seems to work with package example

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I am trying to use the KMggplot2 plugin for Rcmdr. It only seems to work with the built it data set dataKm. [image] When I try to use other data sets such as lung, I get no plot - just the error message "numbers of columns of arguments do not match. Here is the code for each plot attempt.
Here is the code when I try using the lung data even without attempting to have a number at risk list.

```
     library(survival, pos=17)
data(lung, package="survival") 
sapply(c("ggplot2", "grid"), require, character.only = TRUE)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: grid
ggplot2    grid 
   TRUE    TRUE 
.df <- data.frame(x = lung$time, y = lung$status, z = factor("At risk"))
.df <- .df[do.call(order, .df[, c("z", "x"), drop = FALSE]), , drop = FALSE]
.fit <- survival::survfit(survival::Surv(time = x, event = y, type = "right") ~ z,  .df)
.fit <- data.frame(x = .fit$time, y = .fit$surv, nrisk = .fit$n.risk, nevent =    .fit$n.event, ncensor= .fit$n.censor, upper = .fit$upper, lower = .fit$lower)
.df <- unique(.df)
.df <- .fit <- data.frame(.fit, .df[, c("z"), drop = FALSE])
Error in data.frame(.fit, .df[, c("z"), drop = FALSE]) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 186, 199
.df <- .fit <- rbind(unique(data.frame(x = 0, y = 1, nrisk = NA, nevent = NA,     ncensor = NA, upper = 1, lower = 1, .df[, c("z"), drop = FALSE])), .fit)
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match
.cens <- subset(.fit, ncensor == 1)
.plot <- ggplot(data = .fit, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z)) + geom_step(data =     subset(.fit, !is.na(upper)), aes(y = upper), size = 1, lty = 2, alpha = 0.5,    show_guide = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) +
 geom_step(data = subset(.fit, !is.na(lower)), +   aes(y = lower), size = 1, lty = 2, alpha = 0.5, show_guide = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)   + 
geom_step(size =1.5)+         geom_linerange(data = .cens, aes(x = x, ymin = y, ymax =  y + 0.02), size = 1.5) +     
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 900, by = 300), limits  = c(0, 900)) +     scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0.01, 0)) + 
 scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + xlab("Time from entry") + 
ylab("Proportion of survival") + 
theme_gray(base_size = 14, base_family = "serif") 
Error in +geom_step(size = 1.5) : invalid argument to unary operator+
theme(legend.position = "none")
Error in inherits(x, "theme") : argument "e2" is missing, with no default
 print(.plot)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found
```

Comment: I tried looking at the code in the second panel but realized that my questions should already have had answers in the form of comments. Generally throwing pages of code into an SO question with no real description of the data or comments to check for error free progress will not prompt useful answers. (You should also learn to format your code with line-breaks at sensible positions.)

Comment: I'll revise the question.

Answer (score 1):

I just received this response from the developer who said that an update would be uploaded by the end of the month:
"We found a bug was caused by a tie data handling.The following code can be used."

```
    sapply(c("ggplot2", "grid"), require, character.only = TRUE)
.df <- data.frame(x = lung$time, y = lung$status, z = factor("At risk"))
.df <- .df[do.call(order, .df[, c("z", "x"), drop = FALSE]), , drop = FALSE]
.fit <- survival::survfit(survival::Surv(time = x, event = y, type = "right") ~ z, .df)
.fit <- data.frame(x = .fit$time, y = .fit$surv, nrisk = .fit$n.risk,
               nevent = .fit$n.event, ncensor= .fit$n.censor, upper = .fit$upper, lower = .fit$lower)
.df <- .df[!duplicated(.df$x), ]
.df <- .fit <- data.frame(.fit, .df[, c("z"), drop = FALSE])
.df <- .fit <- rbind(unique(data.frame(x = 0, y = 1, nrisk = NA, nevent = NA, ncensor = NA, upper = 1, lower = 1, .df[, c("z"), drop = FALSE])), .fit)
.cens <- subset(.fit, ncensor == 1) .plot <- ggplot(data = .fit, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z)) + 
geom_step(data = subset(.fit, !is.na(upper)), aes(y = upper), size = 1, lty = 2, alpha = 0.5, show_guide = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) +
geom_step(data = subset(.fit, !is.na(lower)), aes(y = lower), size = 1, lty = 2, alpha = 0.5, show_guide = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) + 
geom_step(size = 1.5) +
geom_linerange(data = .cens, aes(x = x, ymin = y, ymax = y + 0.02), size = 1.5) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 900, by = 300), limits = c(0, 900)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0.01, 0)) + 
scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
xlab("Time from entry") + 
ylab("Proportion of survival") + 
theme_gray(base_size = 14, base_family = "serif") + 
theme(legend.position = "none")
print(.plot)
```